# Mail function on Live Server is Not sending Mails

Tags: php, email

I have a website and have enabled to `send mail` using the By default mail function of php

My code is this

I have tested it from other posts also.. and for me it is correct.. but it is still not sending the message. Please tell me.. where is the problem

```
<?php                    
    include_once './config.php';       
    $con=mysqli_connect(mysql_host,mysql_user,mysql_password,mysql_database);

    $Roll = $_REQUEST['UserName'];   
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else 
    {                
            $confirmCode = md5(uniqid(rand()));

            $tbl_name1 = "temp_forgot_acc";
            $orderCheck = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE EmailId = '$Roll'";

            mysqli_query($con,$orderCheck);

            $order = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name1 (EmailId,confirm_code) VALUES ('$Roll','$confirmCode')";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$order);
            //if($result)
           // {
                // ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------

                // send e-mail to ...
                $to=$Roll;

                    // Your subject
                $subject="Your Forgot Pass link here";

                // From
                $header = 'From: Admin <admin@test.com>' . "\r\n";

                // Your message
                $message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";                        
                $message.="http://www.test.com/test.html?passkey=$confirmCode&Email=$Roll";

                // send email
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);                        
         //   } 
                            echo '{"data":[';
        echo "{" . '"Finish":'.'"YES"}';                        

        echo ']}';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    exit();
?>
```

I am able to insert it in the database... but it is not sending the maill.

Comment: many hosting providers dont allow to send email from non existing email id, in you case admin@test.com i dont think its exist. try to create one and then try.

Comment: check by echo $to returns correct email address or not..

Comment: If you are trying to send it from Localhost chances are you don't have email server running

Comment: I am actually using a correct email id...

Comment: instead of test.. it is  a real email id..

Comment: the way you are returning JSON is alos not good, you better use json_encode

Comment: I just now checked.. that it is sending the mails to spam folder.. how to get it in main inbox

Answer (score 0):

Try code something like this in your application:

```
$from = "sender id" // sender must be valid
$subject = "subject";
$message = 'mail from'.$from.'sender';
$to = "receiver id";
// send mail
$headers = 'From: <test@test.com>' . "\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

and check what you have in $to value..email id must be correct.